# Finding indexes of non-empty fields in text files

Tags: regex, perl, parsing

I have a very large text file whose lines are comma-separated values. Some values are missing. For each line, I'd like to print the index and value of all the non-empty fields.

For example, a line might look like

```
,,10.3,,,,5.2,3.1,,,,,,,
```

in which case the output I want is

```
2,10.3,6,5.2,7,3.1
```

I know how to accomplish this by first splitting the input into an array, and then going through the array with a for loop, but these are huge files (multi-gigabyte) and I'm wondering if there is a faster way. (e.g. using some advanced regexp)

Answer (score 3):

I haven't benchmarked it yet, but I would assume

```
my $line = ",,10.3,,,,5.2,3.1,,,,,,,";
my $index = 0;
print join ",",
    map {join ",", @$_}
    grep $_->[1],
    map {[$index++, $_]}
    split ",", $line;
```

is faster than some advanced regexp.

The problem is that as long as you have to know the index, you still have to keep track of those missing entries somehow.

Something like this might not be too slow though:

```
my ($i, @vars);

while ($line =~ s/^(,*)([^,]+)//) {
    push @vars, $i += length($1), $2;
}

print join ",", @vars;
```

You could probably leave out the first capturing group and use `pos()` to work out the index.

Here's a comparison of my two suggestions and sin's with 1M iterations:

```
           Rate flesk1    sin flesk2
flesk1  87336/s     --    -8%   -27%
sin     94518/s     8%     --   -21%
flesk2 120337/s    38%    27%     --
```

Seems like my regex works better than I thought.

Comment: You could probably use `(,*)` to handle a value at the beginning .. `x,,10.3,,,,5.2,3.1,,,,,`

Comment: Thanks. I somehow didn't think of that eventuality.

Comment: Added some benchmarks. You can significantly increase performance by removing the s/// operator and just making it global: `while ($line =~ /(,*)([^,]+)/g) {` ..

Comment: Nice. Makes sense when you think about it.

Answer (score 2):

You might be able to mix and match regex and code -

`$line =~ /(?{($cnt,@ary)=(0,)})^(?:([^,]+)(?{push @ary,$cnt; push @ary,$^N})|,(?{$cnt++}))+/x`
`and print join( ',', @ary);`

expanded -

```
$line =~ /
  (?{($cnt,@ary)=(0,)})
  ^(?:
      ([^,]+) (?{push @ary,$cnt; push @ary,$^N})
    | , (?{$cnt++})
   )+
/x
and print join( ',', @ary);
```

**some benchmarks**

With a slight tweak of flesk's and sln's (look for fleskNew and slnNew),
the winner is the fleskNew when the substitution operator is removed.

code -

```
use Benchmark qw( cmpthese ) ;
$samp = "x,,10.3,,q,,5.2,3.1,,,ghy,g,,l,p";
$line = $samp;

cmpthese( -5, {

    flesk1 => sub{
                    $index = 0;
                    join ",",
                       map {join ",", @$_}
                       grep $_->[1],
                       map {[$index++, $_]}
                       split ",", $line;
           },

    flesk2 => sub{
              ($i, @vars) = (0,);
              while ($line =~ s/^(,*)([^,]+)//) {
                  push @vars, $i += length($1), $2;
              }
              $line = $samp;
           },

    fleskNew => sub{
              ($i, @vars) = (0,);
              while ($line =~ /(,*)([^,]+)/g) {
                  push @vars, $i += length($1), $2;
              }
           },

    sln1 => sub{
              $line =~ /
                 (?{($cnt,@ary)=(0,)})
                 ^(?:
                     ([^,]+) (?{push @ary,$cnt; push @ary,$^N})
                   | , (?{$cnt++})
                  )+
               /x
           },

    slnNew => sub{
              $line =~ /
                 (?{($cnt,@ary)=(0,)})
                 (?:
                     (,*) (?{$cnt += length($^N)})
                     ([^,]+) (?{push @ary, $cnt,$^N})
                   )+
               /x
           },

} );
```

numbers -

```
            Rate   flesk1     sln1   flesk2   slnNew fleskNew
flesk1   20325/s       --     -51%     -52%     -56%     -60%
sln1     41312/s     103%       --      -1%     -10%     -19%
flesk2   41916/s     106%       1%       --      -9%     -17%
slnNew   45978/s     126%      11%      10%       --      -9%
fleskNew 50792/s     150%      23%      21%      10%       --
```

**some benchmarks 2**

Adds Birei's in-line replacment and trim (all-in-one) solution.

Abberations:

Flesk1 is modified to remove the final 'join' as it is not included in
the other regex solutions. This gives it a chance to bench better.

Birei deviates in the bench as it modifies the original string to be the final solution.
That aspect can't be taken out. The difference between Birei1 and BireiNew is that the
new one removes the final ','.

Flesk2, Birei1 and BireiNew have the additional overhead of restoring the original string
due to the substitution operator.

The winner still looks like FleskNew ..

code -

```
use Benchmark qw( cmpthese ) ;
$samp = "x,,10.3,,q,,5.2,3.1,,,ghy,g,,l,p";
$line = $samp;

cmpthese( -5, {

    flesk1a => sub{
                $index = 0;
                map {join ",", @$_}
                   grep $_->[1],
                   map {[$index++, $_]}
                   split ",", $line;
       },

    flesk2 => sub{
          ($i, @vars) = (0,);
          while ($line =~ s/^(,*)([^,]+)//) {
              push @vars, $i += length($1), $2;
          }
          $line = $samp;
       },

    fleskNew => sub{
          ($i, @vars) = (0,);
          while ($line =~ /(,*)([^,]+)/g) {
              push @vars, $i += length($1), $2;
          }
       },

    sln1 => sub{
          $line =~ /
             (?{($cnt,@ary)=(0,)})
             ^(?:
                 ([^,]+) (?{push @ary,$cnt; push @ary,$^N})
               | , (?{$cnt++})
              )+
           /x
       },

    slnNew => sub{
          $line =~ /
             (?{($cnt,@ary)=(0,)})
             (?:
                 (,*) (?{$cnt += length($^N)})
                 ([^,]+) (?{push @ary, $cnt,$^N})
             )+
           /x
       },


    Birei1 => sub{
          $i = -1;
          $line =~
          s/
           (?(?=,+)
               ( (?: , (?{ ++$i }) )+ )
             | (?<no_comma> [^,]+ ,? ) (?{ ++$i })
           )
          /
          defined $+{no_comma} ? $i . qq[,] . $+{no_comma} : qq[]
          /xge;

          $line = $samp;
       },

    BireiNew => sub{
          $i = 0;
          $line =~ 
          s/
            (?: , (?{++$i}) )*
            (?<data> [^,]* )
            (?: ,*$ )?
            (?= (?<trailing_comma> ,?) )
          /
            length $+{data} ? "$i,$+{data}$+{trailing_comma}" : ""
          /xeg;

          $line = $samp;
       },

} );
```

results -

```
            Rate BireiNew   Birei1  flesk1a   flesk2     sln1   slnNew fleskNew
BireiNew  6030/s       --     -18%     -74%     -85%     -86%     -87%     -88%
Birei1    7389/s      23%       --     -68%     -82%     -82%     -84%     -85%
flesk1a  22931/s     280%     210%       --     -44%     -45%     -51%     -54%
flesk2   40933/s     579%     454%      79%       --      -2%     -13%     -17%
sln1     41752/s     592%     465%      82%       2%       --     -11%     -16%
slnNew   47088/s     681%     537%     105%      15%      13%       --      -5%
fleskNew 49563/s     722%     571%     116%      21%      19%       5%       --
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a regex (although I'm sure it can be simpler):

```
s/(?(?=,+)((?:,(?{ ++$i }))+)|(?<no_comma>[^,]+,?)(?{ ++$i }))/defined $+{no_comma} ? $i . qq[,] . $+{no_comma} : qq[]/ge;
```

Explanation:

```
s/PATTERN/REPLACEMENT/ge              # g -> Apply to all occurrences
                                      # e -> Evaluate replacement as a expression.
(?
  (?=,+)                              # Check for one or more commas.
  ((?:,(?{ ++$i }))+)                 # If (?=,+) was true, increment variable '$i' with each comma found.                
  |
  (?<no_comma>[^,]+,?)(?{ ++$i })     # If (?=,+) was false, get number between comma and increment the $i variable only once.
)
defined $+{no_comma}                  # If 'no_comma' was set in 'pattern' expression...
$i . qq[,] . $+{no_comma}             # insert the position just before it.
qq[]                                  # If wasn't set, it means that pattern matched only commas, so remove then.
```

---

My test:

Content of `script.pl`:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

while ( <DATA> ) { 
    our $i = -1; 
    chomp;
    printf qq[Orig = $_\n];
    s/(?(?=,+)((?:,(?{ ++$i }))+)|(?<no_comma>[^,]+,?)(?{ ++$i }))/defined $+{no_comma} ? $i . qq[,] . $+{no_comma} : qq[]/ge;
#    s/,\Z//;
    printf qq[Mod = $_\n\n];

}

__DATA__
,,10.3,,,,5.2,3.1,,,,,,,
10.3,,,,5.2,3.1,,,,,,,
,10.3,,,,5.2,3.1
,,10.3,5.2,3.1,
```

Run the script like:

```
perl script.pl
```

And output:

```
Orig = ,,10.3,,,,5.2,3.1,,,,,,,
Mod = 2,10.3,6,5.2,7,3.1,

Orig = 10.3,,,,5.2,3.1,,,,,,,
Mod = 0,10.3,4,5.2,5,3.1,

Orig = ,10.3,,,,5.2,3.1
Mod = 1,10.3,5,5.2,6,3.1

Orig = ,,10.3,5.2,3.1,
Mod = 2,10.3,3,5.2,4,3.1,
```

As you can see, it keeps last comma. I don't know how to remove it without an extra regex, just uncomment `s/,\Z//;` in previous code.

Comment: In regex, everything matches when its either ',' or not ',', sort of like [\s\S] (ergo split). Given that, the '*' (used as greedy) quantifier is really all thats needed.If you are doing everything at once (ie: substitution, stripping, boundry conditions) without storing to an array, the final ',' can probably be eliminated with something like this - `s/(?:,(?{++$i}))*(?<data>[^,]*)(?:,*$)?(?=(?<trailing_comma>,?))/length $+{data} ? "$i,$+{data}$+{trailing_comma}" : ""/xeg`. I'm posting new benches with sln, flex and yours.